# Video converter to convert any format to light-weight avi format(for mobile and portable multimedia devices)

Tags: video, conversion, avi, 3gp

[These answers](https://superuser.com/questions/58132/convert-large-mov-file-to-avi-or-other-small-file-format) don't satisfy MY needs. My mobile supports .3gp and .avi formats

3gp files are always smaller in size but with least quality (especially audio part)

Avi (certainly) exhibits better quality but the video converter I am using (namely [Xillisoft VidConverter](http://www.xilisoft.com/video-converter.html)) outputs avi file with very high size, which isn't suitable for portable devices

So I'm looking for (essentially free or open source) software that creates smaller files with a better quality than 3gp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool called [**Xvid4PSP**](http://www.winnydows.com/) which you can check. <sup>(requires silverlight for that site)</sup>.
Here is a [forum HOWTO page](http://forum.winnydows.com/viewforum.php?f=37) that can be reached without silverlight.